# R question: I modified two categorical columns, how do I embedded back into the original dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, population

I'm fairly new to R, and after taking a 2 hour free course on Youtube, I feel no better. I'm trying to learn so I hope someone can help me out! I feel close to the answer but here I am :D I have a dataset, and I've modified the two columns by editing them as strings (characters). They consists of first(1st column) and last names(2nd column) of people so I was ordered to remove punctuations therefore, had to edit them as strings.Now I'm unsure how to add them back into the dataframe. Here is where I'm at.

```
    # FILE: Vaccine_CSV
    # INSTALL AND LOAD PACKAGES 
    library(datasets)  # Load base packages manually

    # Use pacman to load add-on packages as desired
    pacman::p_load(pacman, rio) 

    # Importing CSV from desktop
    Vaccine_CSV <- import("~/Desktop/Vaccine CSV.csv")

    # Summary 
    summary(Vaccine_CSV)

    # Transform lowercases in data into upper case
    Vaccine_CSV = as.data.frame(sapply(Vaccine_CSV, toupper))


    Vaccine_CSV$FirstName
    Vaccine_CSV$LastName

    # Trim the spaces between the names
    trimws(Vaccine_CSV$FirstName) 
    trimws(Vaccine_CSV$LastName) 

    # First and last names combined
    FirstNameFixed<- Vaccine_CSV [, c(3)]
    LastNFixed<- Vaccine_CSV [, c(4)]

     # Trimming inside the first name column
    FirstNameFixed <- gsub("\\-", "", FirstNameFixed)
    FirstNameFixed <- gsub("\\s", "", FirstNameFixed)
    FirstNameFixed <- gsub("\\'", "", FirstNameFixed)

    # Trimming inside last name column 
    LastNFixed<- gsub("\\-", "", LastNFixed)
    LastNFixed <- gsub("\\s", "", LastNFixed)
    LastNFixed<- gsub("\\'", "", LastNFixed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `dplyr` package will be a friend here.

Once you have applied toupper, your code can be writen as shown:

```
library(dplyr)
Vaccine_CSV$FirstName <- trimws(.) %>% gsub("\\-", "",.) %>% gsub("\\s", "",.) %>% gsub("\\'", "",.)
```

and dataframe columns will be changed.

On the other hand, if you want to work with lists or vectors and not with data frames, once you have `FirstNameFixed` and `LastNFixed` with all operations done, you can combine them:

```
new_df <- cbind(FirstNameFixed,LastNFixed)
```

And if you want to substitute them into data frame:

```
Vaccine_CSV$FirstName <- FirstNameFixed
Vaccine_CSV$LastName <- LastNFixed
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I just figured it out before you responded but thank you!